# What is a royal city?

Tags: joshua

Joshua 10

> <sup>**1**</sup>Now it came to pass, when Adonizedek king of Jerusalem had heard how Joshua had taken Ai, and had utterly destroyed it; as he had done to Jericho and her king, so he had done to Ai and her king; and how the inhabitants of Gibeon had made peace with Israel, and were among them; <sup>**2**</sup>That they feared greatly, because Gibeon was a great city, as one of the **royal cities**, and because it was greater than Ai, and all the men thereof were mighty.

What is a royal city?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We would probably call it a "capital" city today; but we are not generally governed by kings as nations usually were in those times.

> And David arose, and he passed over with the six hundred men that were
> with him unto **Achish**, the son of Maoch, **king of Gath**. (1 Samuel 27:2,
> KJV)
>
> And David said **unto Achish**, If I have now found grace in thine eyes,
> let them give me a place in some town in the country, that I may dwell
> there: for why should thy servant dwell in **the royal city** **with thee?**
> (1 Samuel 27:5, KJV)

Achish was the king who lived in Gath and who, at David's request, gave him another city, Ziklag, in which to live.  Because it was the city of the king, Gath was a "royal city."

> And Joab fought against Rabbah of the children of Ammon, and took **the
> royal city.** (2 Samuel 12:26, KJV)

Rabbah would have been the capital for the Ammonites, being their "royal city."

The text in the question is likened to one of the royal cities, which implies that it is not, itself, a royal city.  Its size was like that of a royal city.  The Hebrew actually has a prepositional phrase, i.e. "like one" in place of the English "as one" which could be either adverbial in usage or a prepositional phrase.